# no aparece var/www en Lamp Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

De que forma puedo hacer que aparezca esta carpeta www en el directorio var leí algo de los permisos , pero debido a que no se encuentra la capeta no puedo darle permisos saludos gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Si no te aparece el directorio `www` luego de configurar lo que se conoce como `Lamp` puedes crear tu mismo el directorio con el siguiente comando

```
sudo mkdir /var/www
```

Una vez hecho esto debes configurar los permisos de dicho directorio para que tu usuario pueda leer y escribir sobre este sin problemas, básicamente es hacer lo siguiente:

```
- Agregar tu usuario al grupo www-data

  usermod -a -G www-data tu_usuario


- Cambiar el  dueño y grupo del directorio www a www-data

  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www


- Dar permisos de lectura y escritura a los miembros del grupo 
  al que pertenece el directorio www

  chmod -R g+rwx /var/www
```

Comment: hice todo lo que me dijiste y continuo sin tener permisos      "drwxrwxr-x  2 root www-data 4096 mar 12 19:55 www"

Comment: Reinicia `Apache` o el que estés usando, si aun no toma los cambios cierra sesión en tu computador y vuelvela a iniciar

Comment: Solucionado el tema de los permisos , De que forma hago dirección a mis proyectos ? saludos gracias, tendre que crear la carpeta httdocs?

Comment: a que te refieres con dirección?

Comment: ejemplo "127.0.0.1/proyecto/" debido a que me sale proyecto no encontrado, y este esta dentro de la carpeta www

Comment: actualmente funciona 127.0.0.1/dashboard/ me manda a la pantalla principal de xampp , pero no consigo ingresar al proyecto que copie dentro de www/proyecto

Comment: a http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/ también puedo entrar sin problemas , pero a mi proyecto aun no lo consigo gracias

Comment: Debes mirar que tu root directory en Apache o lo que uses apunte al directorio `/var/www` luego de eso reiniciar el servicio y probar si funciona

Comment: como puedo acceder al directorio root ? en que ruta se encuentra por desperfecto ?

Comment: actualmente no puedo entrar al directorio root , ahi se encuentra el directorio apache?

Comment: Debes buscar el fichero de configuración y cambiar el document root, [Aquí](http://www.tecmint.com/change-root-directory-of-apache-web-server/) explican como hacer lo que te digo,

Comment: ese el problema que tengo que no puedo acceder al DocumentRoot debido a que no se su ruta o no tengo permisos ejecuto javier@Samsung:/$ cd /etc/apache/apache2.conf
bash: cd: /etc/apache/apache2.conf: No existe el archivo o el directorio
javier@Samsung:/$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
bash: cd: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default: No existe el archivo o el directorio disculpa pero estoy algo confundido no pense que fuera tan complicado configurar un servidor local en ubuntu

Comment: debes editar alguno de esos ficheros no ejecutarlos [Aquí](http://viviryaprenderweb.com/como-cambiar-el-documentroot-en-apache/) te dejo otro ejemplo

Comment: dashboard y phpmyadmin te aparecen porque lamp los "monta" sobre `127.0.0.1` pero su dirección física está en otro lado. Vas a tener que entrar en `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` y crear dentro de esa carpeta (con sudo) tus sitios, tomando como molde el ejemplo `0000-default` que hay ahí dentro

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tú instalaste el programa `Xampp`. Debes saber que `Xampp` y `LAMP` son dos maneras diferentes de tener un servidor apache en tu Ubuntu. No es lo mismo y por lo tanto la estructura y ubicación de sus carpetas suelen ser diferentes.

El programa `Xampp` tiene como raíz del servidor apache la carpeta `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`. Esta es la carpeta que tú estás buscando.

El servidor LAMP si se encuentra en `/var/www`. Esta carpeta no la encuentras porque no instalaste `LAMP`, instalaste `Xampp`.

Referencias:

- https://raul432.webnode.es/news/a10-diferencias-entre-lamp-y-xampp/
- http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-xampp-ubuntu-18-04/